# Not show styles.xml in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I have created an app in Android Studio in Windows. Now I have a problem with the resource file "`style.xml`". It does not display/exist. Check the attached image:
[Image of XML files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sH26.png)
How can I display it?
Thanks!

Comment: has the style.xml file been replaced with theme.xml?
I checked the theme folder. In theme folder have themes.xml.

Comment: it seems like anything you used to put in "styles" you can now put in "themes" - no difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the new versions of Android studio styles.xml change to themes.xml

Answer (score 15):

Newer templates provided by android studio make use of `themes.xml` instead of `styles.xml`

[image: as you can see here]