# styles.xml file is not generated by android studio? Theme module is there inside values module

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

[[image: This is the hierarchy.This is android version I am using]

Is there any specifications of API level where that file will be generated.

Comment: Due to this issue i am unable to do my project. Please help. :))

Comment: you can create styles.xml file yourself without android studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not show styles.xml in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284707/not-show-styles-xml-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Create new resource file in values package:

[image]

Name your file:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--Code here-->
</resources>
```

Comment: I did this but it shows the error theme is not recognized so linking cant be done successfully.