# Which themes.xml file should we use instead of style.xml in android

Tags: android, android-theme

In my android studio, there is no `style.xml` file.
There is a themes folder having two `themes.xml` files.
Please tell which `themes.xml` file should we use for android tab functionality.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not show styles.xml in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284707/not-show-styles-xml-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got changed in **Android studio 4.1**

Actually, in the older versions of Android studio, if you want to enable dark mode in your app, you have to manually create and define the properties in your dark theme XML file, but now it is automatically generated as mostly all new apps are moving towards dark mode in their applications.

You can still delete these files from your Android studio project if it doesn't fit in your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two `themes.xml` in the new Android Studio project templates.
One is for a light theme and the other one is for a dark theme.

More info on [dark theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme)

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a dark theme (or black theme) is very easy today thanks to

> Theme.DayNight and
> AppCompatDelegate

Android comes to us allowing us to declare

> night/colors.xml

and

> night/styles.xml

Full example here: https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/DarkTheme